# I want to split conafile.py into two, with both files containing some methods and then inherit the methods of second .py file to conanfile.py

Tags: python, conan

I have two files(conanfile.py and parent_conanfile.py).

*conanfile.py*

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake
from parent_conanfile import Parent_ASAR
import os

class ASAR(ConanFile):    

    name = "hello1"
    author = "WindRunner"
    
    revision_mode = "scm"
    scm = {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "auto",
    "revision": "auto"
    }

    settings = "os", "os_build", "arch", "arch_build", "compiler", "build_type"   

    def package(self):
         self.copy("*", src="Configurator", dst="Configurator", links=True)
         self.copy("*", src="Generators", dst="Generators")
```

*parent_conanfile.py*

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake
import os

class Parent_ASAR(object):

   name = "hello"
   author = "WindRunner"
  
   def source(self):
       pass

   def configure(self):
       pass

   def requirements(self):
       pass

   def build(self):
       compiler = self.settings.compiler
       compiler_version = self.settings.compiler.version
       arch = self.settings.arch
       os = str(self.settings.os).lower()
       build_type = str(self.settings.build_type).lower()

       toolchain_file = f"CMakeSupport/toolchain/{compiler}/{compiler}-{compiler_version}/{arch}/{os}_{build_type}.toolchain"
       self.output.info(f"Used toolchain file: {toolchain_file}")
       model_dir = ("Examples/DeliveryDefaultModel")     

       for target in self.targetList: 
            self.run(
               "./BuildHelper/BuildHelper \
                --cmake-options-file BuildHelper/config/development.json \
                --model-dir {0} \
                --target {1} \
                --sip-dir {2} \
                --build-dir {3} \
                --install {4} \
                --cmake-toolchain-file {5} \

               ".format(
                 model_dir,
                 target,
                 self.source_folder,
                 self.build_folder,
                 self.package_folder,
                 toolchain_file

                 )

             )

   def package_info(self):
       
       self.cpp_info.includedirs = ['include']
       self.cpp_info.libdirs = ['lib']

   def deploy(self):

       self.copy("*", src="etc", dst="etc")
       self.copy("*", src="opt", dst="opt")
       self.copy("*", src="sbin", dst="sbin")
       self.copy("*", src="scripts", dst="usr/local")
       self.copy("*", src="BuildHelper", dst="BuildHelper")
```

When I run the command:

```
conan create . hello1/1.0@
```

When I run this command I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: hello1/1.0@swf/testing: Cannot load recipe.
Error loading conanfile at '/home/ak/.conan/data/hello1/1.0/swf/testing/export/conanfile.py': Unable to load conanfile in /home/ak/.conan/data/hello1/1.0/swf/testing/export/conanfile.py
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 684, in _load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/ak/.conan/data/hello1/1.0/swf/testing/export/conanfile.py", line 15, in <module>

    from parent_conanfile import Parent_ASAR

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parent_conanfile'
```

Though, if I create another method in the class and explicitly call that method in conanfile.py, the method seems to run, but still gives the same error.
Does conan allows such a way to import half of the recipe from another file?

Comment: You are looking for Conan [python requires](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/extending/python_requires.html#python-requires) feature. It's exactly you need, re-use recipe parts.

Comment: @uilianries Thanks. I have looked into the doc and i think this might work.